# Breadcrumbs not showing parent, just Home > [insertPageNameHere]

Tags: breadcrumbs, navigation

[insertPageNameHere] is just a placeholder. It displays things like

> Home > About

and

> Home > News

and

> Home > How to carve wood

But **not**

> Home > News > How to carve wood

which is what I want it to display as that's how you navigate to the page "How to carve wood".

I've been googling this for the better part of today and I've tried several different modules, but I've come to realize that there's probably a fundamental flaw in how I use Drupal in general. 
When I check the "Provide menu link" in a "News" content type page I get the desired behavior from the breadcrumbs, but then additionally my navigation bar gets a dropdown when I hover "News", and in that dropdown is every single page of the "News" content type.

I don't know what to do or what is wrong, but it's probably something about the arrangement of my site. Perhaps there are some fundemental breadcrumb/organizing principles I've missed?

Comment: Have you tried [Path Breadcrumbs](https://www.drupal.org/project/path_breadcrumbs)? Or the incredibly configurable and well written [Crumbs](https://www.drupal.org/project/crumbs)?

Comment: I have not! I'll try it out! But I still feel like this could be accomplished simply with core, don't you?

Comment: Yeh, my problem is that behind the scenes, "How to carve wood" is not actually a child of "News" for some reason. That's what I need to fix, and I don't really see how Path Breadcrumbs does that.

Comment: What method have you used to establish the content hierarchy if not through the menu? How would "How to carve wood" know that it's a child of whatever node? Unless you've done something to tell Drupal that they're related, it's pretty reasonable for it not to know

Comment: Yes, indeed! I haven't really done anything of that sort as I'm not quite sure how to! How do I go about doing that?
I don't really see where to do it through Home » Administration » Structure » Menus

Comment: I just enabled the book module and will try that out, but I'd assume this was possible without enabling any more modules? This is pretty standard behavior afterall

Comment: You've lost me, what's the standard behaviour you're expecting to see? For a CMS to automagically know what you consider to be parent/child relationships, without you giving it any indication of what that relationship is, or that it even exists? That's quite some expectation :)

Comment: No, I mean that building a hierarchical relationship and being able to show breadcrumbs as "Home >> News >> How to carve wood" is incredibly standard, and I'd expect that you don't have to enable additional module(s) to be able to establish this kind of behavior. I am aware that I have to set up the hierarchy myself, but I'm not sure how to! I'm just saying I'd assume it was possible for me to set it up without enabling yet another module.

Comment: Absolutely - the menu system provides you with that exact functionality, but it doesn't give you what _you're_ specifically looking for (because you have a theme that converts the sub menu items into drop downs, or maybe the superfish module installed or something). That's why Drupal is a modular system, so it can be extended easily when the core functionality doesn't cover your exact use case

Comment: Ah, ok, cool! So what I was doing with the "Provide menu link" was possibly the way to go, but it's my theme that does something that I don't want? Is the only solution to change my theme, or can I disable the dropdown thingy? Thanks for your help so far, it's given me some more understanding!